# How can I display MySql data in my python script?

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a calendar project combined with a raspberry pi, which displays appointments of my web calendar threw a python script.

```
class getData:
    def getData(self):
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM appointdatetitle')
        mycursorresult = mycursor.fetchall()

Dataresult = Label(framecalendar, text=getData())
Dataresult.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
```

I want to display the data of phpmyadmin line for line.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the fetched data from your method. And this class definition has no use.

```
def getData():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM appointdatetitle')
    mycursorresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    return mycursorresult

Dataresult = Label(framecalendar, text=getData())
Dataresult.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
```